# What is fair annual profit for an investor

Tags: investing, software

I have a dot com company which steadily generates income. I now need some cash injection and found some investors. They invest some money and the deal is to pay them out in equal monthly payments for one year. I don't know what's the profit we should agree on for one year. What would be the fair profit we should agree on in terms of best practices and current market situation? 50% of profits is too steep I would say. 25% would probably be the sum I would be comfortable with but I am not sure they would too.

Comment: As stated, your question is a bit ambiguous. Are you offering a rate of return, i.e. a percent on their money? Or a portion of your profits, but for just a year? Keep in mind, *dot com* is now pretty meaningless. Do you sell a good, a service, a dream? Any established business can talk to a bank and build a relationship to get reasonable financing.

Comment: "pay them out in equal monthly payments for one year" -- That sounds like a bond or loan rather than an investment, since you are promising them a specific rate of return on their money rather than a percentage of profits or an ownership stake in the company.

Comment: This question is not about _personal_ finance any more because it is no longer a sole proprietorship but rather about a limited partnership with a General Partner (the OP) and a bunch of Limited Partners (the investors).

Comment: Thank you all for the input. All valid points. I learned a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question isn't "fair", it's "how much do you have to give them in order to get them to trust you with the money for a year rather than doing something else with it, and does that exceed what you are willing/able to give them, and how sure are you that you can either do without the money or find it elsewhere?"

This has to be negotiated. There is no standard answer, since there is no standard company or lender. Heck, even a simple bank loan is a negotiation, though that usually takes the form of shopping around for an acceptable rate and their deciding whether they'll accept you rather than going back and forth on what rate would be the best compromise.